# Does anybody know is google assistant sdk available for commercial use?

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

Does anybody know that google assistant SDK is available for commercial use or not?

If available how can I buy its License?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Google Assistant SDK Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/terms-of-service), you **may not** commercialize your Project without written permission from Google:

> Google provides the Assistant API only for developmental use on your
> Project devices. You may not:
>
> a. commercialize your Project without written permission from Google;
>
> b. incorporate or use the Assistant API with any standalone software
> applications that are not necessary for operation of your Project
> device; or
>
> c. circumvent the limits Google places on the number of
> queries your Project may issue, Users it may support, or any other
> limit Google may put in place.

Comment: So how to contact them for permission?

Comment: You can submit the form at the bottom of https://developers.google.com/actions/support/